# Как менять цвет шрифта абзаца каждую секунду?

Tags: javascript

```
let text = document.querySelector("#text");

setInterval(function(){
  text.style.color="red";

 if(text.style.color == "red"){
    setInterval(function(){
        text.style.color="green"//* цвет останавливается на зеленом и не меняется
    }, 1000);
 }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let text = document.querySelector("#text");
text.style.color="red";

setInterval(function(){
 if(text.style.color == "red"){
    text.style.color="green";
 } else {
    text.style.color="red";
 }
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Может так? ^-^

```js
let text = document.querySelector("#text");
var color = ['green', 'red', '#070478'],
  colorN = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  text.style.color = color[colorN];
  colorN = colorN == color.length ? 0 : colorN + 1;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="text">Ну типа тут ваш текст</div>
```

Comment: `text.style.color = color[colorN++ % color.length];` - либо короче)